# TFS plugin to use with PyCharm

Tags: tfs, ide, pycharm

I am looking for a free source code management TFS plugin to use with the PyCharm IDE. I've been looking around and cannot seem to get anything to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [TFS Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs-integration).

Based on the description in the page it should be compatible with **PyCharm**

> Compatible with: IntelliJ IDEA  PhpStorm  WebStorm  **PyCharm** 
>   RubyMine  AppCode  GoLand  Rider

Also this for your reference : [Using TFS Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_MS_TFS_Integration.html)

---

**UPDATE:**

It supports **PyCharm Community Edition**, refer to this link for details : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs-integration/update/12400.

That's the only plugin for PyCharm for now. The **IntelliJ IDEA** is required So, you can have a try for **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition** to check if that works for you.

Comment: Will this work with the PyCharm Community Edition IDE? Also, the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is required for the TFS Integration plugin, which is a "pay for" piece of software. Any comments on this appreciated.

Comment: @user2643607 Yes, it supports **PyCharm Community Edition**, refer to this link for details : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs-integration/update/12400. Unfortunately that's the only plugin for  PyCharm for now. I have no chance to check that, however you can have a try for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition to check if that works for you.

Comment: @user2643607 Have you resolved the issue? any udpate?

Comment: I'm not 100% resolved on this issue. I did install the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (375Mb exe) and there is 1 file in this install that I believe made the VCS >> Check out from version control >> TFS selection appear (IdeaWin64.dll). However, when I attempt to clone the repo to my local machine, only the folder / server path I select from the TFS repo gets copied to my local machine. Ie., recursion is not occurring for the entire folder structure and files. Not sure what I'm missing but I'm not totally out of the woods on this yet.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to go in and delete my server workspaces, created local, started fresh and the repo downloaded fine. I still have somethings to iron out, but this issue has been resolved.